# JavaScript TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь написать скрипт который будет заполнять форму.
Вот страница с формой https://www.kufar.by/ain/create
В браузере FireFox вручную заполняю обязательные поля.

Название товара/услуги  - Телефон Xiaomi mi A3
Категория               - Техника
Подкатегори             - Телефоны
Состояние               - Б/у
Цена                    - 10
Пакет услуг             - Бесплатно

Затем через консоль браузера с помощью JavaScript заполняю поле Описание.
В консоли выполняю команду:

```
$("#body").value="продам телефон xiaomi mi a3 "
```

После выполнения команды - надпись появляется в поле описание.
После этого в низу страницы жму Подать объявление
И надпись в поле ОПИСАНИЕ исчезает и вываливается ошибка о том, что
незаполнено поле описание.

Подскажите правильную команду javascript,
чтобы заполнить текстом control ОПИСАНИЕ
и при этом текст, чтобы не исчез при попытке submit.

Comment: Ваша ссылка требует регистрации. Не думаю, что здесь кто-то будет регистрироваться там, что бы ответить вам на вопрос.

Comment: Таким образом на чужом сайте форму не заполнить, думается. Либо имитировать действия пользователя, либо что-то и как-то через curl - все имхо, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После изменения value в textarea достаточно выполнить `$("#body").focus()`.
На сайте скорее всего стоит валидация по dirty полям, если их не зафокусить, то будет считаться что поле пустое.

Comment: Спасибо огромное именно ваш совет помог.

Comment: @korggrodno поставить галочку за правильный ответ слабо ?

Comment: Поставил. Я просто новичек и не знал об этом. Теперь буду знать. Спасибо. smile